# Regex angular ngModel

Tags: angular, regex

Olá, estou com um problema com regex e angular.

Tenho um input que utiliza ngModel, e estou precisando utilizar um regex nele que impeça o usuário digitar inicialmente um número, ou seja, obrigatoriamente o primeiro digito do input não pode ser um número.

O problema, é que não consigo encontrar um regex que faça isso e não consigo aplicar nenhum regex com ngModel.

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor. Meu input se encontra assim no momento:

```
 <input 
     placeholder="Input name" 
     class="inputs" 
     value="{{input.inputField}}"
     pattern="^[a-z]"
     [(ngModel)]="input[i].inputField" />
```

Agradeço desde já...

Comment: Você pode criar uma função e chamar ela no atributo onKeyDown do seu input, e nela fazer essa validação de primeiro caractere como letra e o restante como números.

Comment: Não é só trocar o `pattern` por `ng-pattern`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern#usage

Comment: usa diretiva, mais fácil

Comment: http://kazale.com/angular-2-mascara-entrada-dados-input-mask-diretivas/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa de expressão regular para fazer esta validação, você pode pegar o **primeiro** valor do `input` com o método [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) e verificar se é um número com o método [isNaN()](https://www.google.com/search?q=isnan%20javascript&oq=isNaN%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.9618j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

**TS**

```
if(e.target.value.substr(0,1) == isNaN(e.key)) {
  this.valores = undefined;
  this.message = true;
  return;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input placeholder="Input name" [(ngModel)]="valores" (keydown)="eventos($event)" 
 [readOnly]="message" (click)="volta()"/>
```

> Pode ver um exemplo funcionando [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-val).